# find location of binary rectangle in a squared binary matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, binary-search

Given a squared binary matrix, I have to find the rectangle of "1's" that sticks to the buttom-right borders of the matrix. Thus, to conclude, what I have to find is the coordinate of the upper-left rectangle corner.

**P.S**: 1. there always is a rectangle, the minimal would be 1*1 at the buttom-right mat's corner.

2. mat's dimension based on the call to 'getupperleft' function (n = mat's dimension)
3. 1s only inside the rectangle, 0s always outside.

To illustrate,

[image]

here the rectangle starts on the column 4, row 3. (upper-left coordinate)

my idea is to use twice the BinarySearch to get the answer in Log(n), but I'm stuck with implementing it, unusual to c++ syntax. thus would appreciate your help!

```
void getUpperLeft(int mat[][N], int n, int &row, int &col);
void main()
{
    int row = -1;
    int col = -1;
    int matrix[8][N] = {
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1} };

}

void getUpperLeft(int mat[][N], int n, int & row, int & col)
{
    int mid = N - (n / 2);
    if (mat[N][mid] == 1 && mat[N][mid-1] == 0)
    {
        col = mid;
    }
    else if (mat[N][mid] == 0 && mat[N][mid+1] == 0)
    {
        getUpperLeft(mat, n/2 , row, col);
    }
    else if (mat[N][mid] == 1 && mat[N][mid+1] == 1)
    {
        getUpperLeft(mat, N-(n/2), row, col);
    }
}
```

Comment: There just isn't enough information here.  Is your input matrix always 7x7?  Will it always contain a contiguous rectangle?  Might it contain other 1s that don't belong to the rectangle?  Is it still a rectangle if there are extraneous adjacent 1s?  There are so many optimizations here depending on what your *actual* conditions are and what your input restrictions look like.

Comment: you're truely correct. 1- the 1s are only inside the rectangle, all the rest will always be 0.  2- matrix size vary, it's based on the call to the function 'getupperleft',i.e: if I call it: getuuperleft(mat,8,col,row) it would be for 8*8 matrix, if I call getuuperleft(mat,9,col,row) it would be for 9*9 matrix.

Comment: find the first 1 in the last row, then find the first 1 in the last column

Comment: @tobi303 This is exactly what I wrote in the post, that I need the BinarySearch twice (once on the last row, and once on the column with the 1 I found on the last row). however I'm having difficulty with **implementation!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you have some problem of dimension hard-coding in your code. Obviously, you should address that in both your code and the following. Having said that, this will work:

```
int findCol(const int matrix[8][8]) {                                                                                                                                                                    
    int lo = 0, hi = 8 - 1;
    while (lo < hi) {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
        if (matrix[7][mid] < 1)
            lo = mid + 1;
        else
            hi = mid;
    }   
    return lo; 
}   


int findRow(const int matrix[8][8]) {
    int lo = 0, hi = 8 - 1;
    while (lo < hi) {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
        if (matrix[mid][7] < 1)
            lo = mid + 1;
        else
            hi = mid;
    }   
    return lo;
}
```

The former function performs a binary search on the last row, and the latter performs a binary search on the last column.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a binary search on the last column to find the first row which has a 1 value, and similarly perform another binary search on the last row to find the first column which has a 1 value. This will give you the top left corner of the rectangle of 1s.

Complexity is O(log n) time , O(1) space

Comment: Yes, I know that this is the method to solve it in 2log(n) = O(log(n)) - mentioned it in the post. however, as I mentioned, I'm having difficulty with the syntax of c++ to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so using the Iterative version of BinarySearch, This is what I did and it works very well:

```
void main()
{

}

void getUpperLeft(int mat[][N], int n, int & row, int & col)
{
    col = getCoordinate(mat, true, 0);
    row = getCoordinate(mat, false, col);
}

//getCoordinate function works using BinarySearch algorithm - log(n) until it finds the desirable coordinate.
int getCoordinate(int mat[][N], bool stat, int y) //[stat="true" - horizontal test], [stat="false"  - vertical test (then "y" parameter is the horizontal coordinate)].
{
    int low = 0, high = N;
    int prev, next;

    while (low < high)
    {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
            if (stat)
            {
                prev = mat[N - 1][mid - 1];
                next = mat[N - 1][mid];
            }
            else
            {
                prev = mat[mid - 1][y];
                next = mat[mid][y];
            }

            /*edge cases*/
        if (mat[0][0] == 1 && mid ==0)
            return 0;
        if (mat[0][N - 1] == 1 && mid ==0)
            return 0;
            /*edge cases*/

        if (next == 1 && prev == 0)
            return mid;
        else if (prev == 0 && next == 0)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (prev == 1 && next == 1)
            high = mid;
    }
}
```